# SOAP connections through a proxy using URLEndpoint

Tags: java, url, soap, proxy

I've had to update a previous java application that requests a SOAP response from an external web service. This service is outside our firewall which now requires us to go through a proxy instead of hitting the URL directly.

Currently the Java App uses URLEndpoint that takes a string for the URL. Usually when I am getting to a URL through a proxy I create a URL like so:

```
URL url = new URL("http", "theproxy.com", 5555, finalUrl);
```

The problem is URLEndpoint only takes a string for the url, I tried to convert URL to string using toExternalForm() but it malformed the URL.

Any ideas as to a way around this?

EDIT: I can't use System.setProperty as this runs with a whole heap of other Java applications in tomcat.

second edit: I can't set a system properties as it will override all other applications running on the server, I can't use jsocks as the proxy we run through squid proxy which does not support socks4/5

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

That's not how proxy's work. The way a proxy works is that you take your normal URL:

```
http://example.com/service
```

and instead of looking up "example.com" and port 80, the message is sent to your proxy host instead (http://theproxy.com:5555).

Java has built in proxy handling using http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort System properties.

So in your case you would need to do:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "theproxy.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "5555");
```

Then your code should, ideally, "Just Work".

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) is a page documenting the proxy properties.

Comment: Yeah, I know proxies don't work like that but just trying everything. Interesting solution though, I'll try and get back to you. Cheers

Comment: I actually can't do this because this sets the tomcat to run through the proxy not just the instance. :( Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use a proxy library (jsocks, rabbit, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Mindas, I'll look into the jsocks library.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) and do as show in [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java) example.

Answer (score 0):

About the URL constructor with individual proxy setting:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29783

(sorry don't have privileges to comment)